# LIMIT 1 in update query updates all rows instead of just one postgres

Tags: postgresql, limit, updates

I have this query which is only supposed to update a row and return the row that is updated but it updates all the rows instead of the limit 1 that is returned from the select.
I am trying to achieve is explicit locking on a row so that no concurrent reads/selects can occur when any of the rows are selected with stats = pending (sort of like a queue)

This is the query:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE tasksq
SET    stats = 'active' 
WHERE  stats = (
         SELECT stats
         FROM   tasksq
         WHERE  stats = 'pending'
         ORDER BY jobid 
         LIMIT 1
         FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
         )
RETURNING *;
COMMIT;
```

If i run only the limit 1 query then it does work and returns 1 row

```
SELECT *
FROM   tasksq
WHERE  stats = 'pending'
ORDER BY jobid 
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

Find snippet of data set below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This subquery

```
     SELECT stats
     FROM   tasksq
     WHERE  stats = 'pending'
     ...
```

will of course return 'pending'. This makes the statement

```
UPDATE tasksq
SET    stats = 'active' 
WHERE  stats = 'pending'
```

So, you update all rows with stats = 'pending' to stats = 'active'.

You probably want

```
UPDATE tasksq
SET    stats = 'active' 
WHERE  jobid = (
         SELECT jobid
         FROM   tasksq
         WHERE  stats = 'pending'
         ORDER BY jobid 
         LIMIT 1
         FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
         )
```

With jobid being the primary key, this updates one row (the one found in the subquery).

Comment: yes which is fine i think but i only want it to update 1 row and not all rows, which is why i placed limit 1 and would like to have that row returned to me

Comment: Okay. This is not "fine" of course, because you *don't* want to update all 'pending' rows. I've updated my answer with what I think you want. It seems you simply confused `stats` with `jobid`.